# Value Calculation issue in Google web HTML App

Tags: google-apps-script

I have created an HTML web app in google script this works like a calculator, This app works fine if I add the input in descending order however if I skip the order and update in put data numbers randomly in any column then I am not getting the output properly

Example:- update the numbers in box number 4 and 5 then update in box number 1 you will find the differences in  total numbers

Please refer the attached sheet for detailed script 
[Project Name- Project Proposal Form](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wvysoIQP_i9H66ImLL78Aa2M2auPbfPggUFU9KxbsRg/edit#gid=486841858)

```js
   $("#rTpe1").keyup(function(e){
      $("#rFor1").val(this.value * $("#PerHourRate1").val());
      $("#rFor3").val( Number($("#rFor1").val()) +Number($("#rFor2").val()))
    });
    
    $("#rTpe2").keyup(function(e){
      $("#rFor2").val(this.value * $("#PerHourRate2").val());
      $("#rFor3").val( Number($("#rFor1").val()) + Number($("#rFor2").val()))
    });
     $("#rTpe12").keyup(function(e){
      $("#rFor12").val(this.value * $("#PerHourRate3").val());
      $("#rFor3").val( Number($("#rFor1").val()) + Number($("#rFor2").val())+ Number($("#rFor12").val()))
    });
    $("#rTpe13").keyup(function(e){
      $("#rFor13").val(this.value * $("#PerHourRate4").val());
      $("#rFor3").val( Number($("#rFor1").val()) + Number($("#rFor2").val())+ Number($("#rFor12").val())+ Number($("#rFor13").val()))
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong, but I think that's the main culprit:

[image]

If your work your way top to bottom, the output in **'#rFor3'** is not affected. For example, if you enter values in the first field (**'#rTpe1'**), this statement

```
Number($("#rFor2").val()))
```

will evaluate to '0' because **'#rFor2'** probably contains an empty string at this point and Number("") will get you a zero. Because all subsequent input fields reference the results of previous calculations (**'rTpe2'** references **'rFor1'**, **'rTpe12'** references both **'rFor1'** and **'rFor2'**, etc), the sum will come out as correct.

Now consider the reverse scenario. For simplicity, let's make all your rates equal to 1. If you enter the value of '5' into **'rTpe12'**, the value of **'rFor3'** will be

```
 Number("") + Number("") + Number(5*1) == 5; //the first two inputs will contain empty strings at this point
```

The output of  **'#rFor3'** would be 5. If you go up a step and enter the value of '2' into **'rTpe2'**, the value of the **'rFor3'** output will change to

```
Number("") + Number(2*1) == 2; the first input will contain an empty string.
```

The code is not easy to understand, so even if this solution doesn't work for you, consider caching your DOM elements to improve performance and make your code more readable. Currently, you are using jQuery selectors to search the DOM over and over again, which is a serious performance drag. You could also store your calculated value as a variable and simply add values to it instead of recalculating on each input. For example

```
$('document').ready(function(){

 var total = 0;
 var input1 = $('#input1');
 var input2 = $('#input1');
 var input3 = $('#input1');
 var output = $('#output');

 input1.keyup(function(e){

var value = Number(this.value);
sum += value;
output.val(sum);

});



});
```